# Create template class which takes template class as argument in a constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, initialization

I have a code which consists of three layers. At the highest level there is a Master class. Then there is a Grid class, that knows the Master, since it uses its functions for general tasks. On a Grid, I can create Fields, which take the Grid as an argument in its constructor. Now, I would like to make both Grid and Field templates, to enable them to contain arbitrary data types.

I don't manage to let Field handle the type that has been given to Grid correctly. In principle he should be able to deduce it. How do I make this work? My example, of course, does not compile yet.

```
#include <vector>

class Master
{
  public:
    Master() {};
};

template<class T>
class Grid
{
  public:
    Grid(Master &masterin) : master(masterin) {};
  private:
    Master &master;
    std::vector<T> data;
};

template<class T>
class Field
{
  public:
    Field(Master &masterin, Grid &gridin) : master(masterin), grid(gridin) {};
  private:
    Master &master;
    Grid   &grid;
    std::vector<T> data;
};

int main()
{
  Master master;
  Grid<int> grid(master);
  Field<double> field(master, grid);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you refer to the "grid" within "Field"? If it really doesn't need to know about the type of Grid, then create an untyped base class for Grid and take the untyped base as the parameter, instead.

Comment: Why do I get a -1 for asking a question with a complete example? If I knew the answer, I wouldn't ask it...

Comment: I don't know. It wasn't me, though. Let me upvote you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class T>
class Field
{
  public:
    Field(Master &, Grid &);
```

This is not valid, you cannot pass an argument of type `Grid` because `Grid` is not a type

```
  private:
    Master &master;
    Grid   &grid;
```

You cannot have a member of type `Grid` because it is not a type

You can fix the constructor by making it a template:

```
template<typename U>
    Field(Master &, Grid<U> &);
```

This will accept any type that is a specialization of the `Grid` template, but you still can't have a member variable of a template, you need to decide what kind of `Grid` you want the member to be, or store it in a flexible type like `boost::any`.

If you want `Field` to be able to work with any kind of `Grid` then it needs another template parameter:

```
template<class T, class U>
class Field
{
  public:
    Field(Master&, Grid<U>&);
  private:
    Master&  master;
    Grid<U>& grid;
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

To deduce the type of `Grid<U>` you can define a generator function:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
  Field<T, U>
  make_field(Master& m, Grid<U>& g)
  { return Field<T, U>(m, g); }

Master master;
Grid<int> grid;
auto field = make_field<double>(master, grid);  // returns Field<double, int>
```

However, without C++11's `auto` keyword that is inconvenient to use and doesn't really help much as you have to spell out the full type anyway:

```
Field<double, int> field = make_field<double>(master, grid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Grid is a template, so it must have a template argument to be useful here. Given your example, it seems that you want Grid and Field to have independent types. This means that Field must be templatized with two parameters- one for itself and one for the Grid it works with.

Comment: But the type of Grid that is being passed to Field is not free, since it has been set before.

Comment: @Chiel, you can't alter the type of `Field` based on its constructor argument. The type has to be set before you construct it. `Field<double>` is a `Field<double>`, it can't vary based on an argument that isn't part of its type

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not make myself clear. I want indeed to have Grid and Field independent types, but I want to avoid to have to pass the type of Grid to the Field constructor, because it has already been decided what kind of type it is during the initialization of grid.

Comment: @Chiel, maybe we didn't make ourselves clear: **You can't do that**. Only function templates can deduce template arguments, not class templates

Comment: @Jonathan, the bold letters made the message come across :)